# Apple command line tool to merge video files

Tags: command-line, macos

Can I use Apple software from the command line to merge two movie files (for instance `mp4` files)? The two movie files have the same audio and video codec and framerate. I am aware that `ffmpeg` can merge files from the command line, but I am looking for an Apple solution.

Comment: Why exactly do you need an apple version and can’t use ffmpeg? Is your laptop managed by your organization? You can install and use homebrew to install ffmpeg without Sudo: https://superuser.com/questions/619498/can-i-install-homebrew-without-sudo-privileges